# Can I define print regions and set different rows to print at the top for pages in each region?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that I would like to print with a set of rows at the top of each page.

I have used the Print Titles option in the past, but this does not help me with my current problem.

This is because the rows to repeat at the top of the page are not completely static.  They change about every 10 pages or so.

Is there any way to define a print region or section of the document that I can apply such settings to specifically?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define a Custom View to save a particular set of print settings, including settings that apply to specific areas of a worksheet.

- First, in Page Layout set the print settings, including the print area, rows to print at top, etc.
- Next, go to `View`->`Custom View`, press the <kbd>Add</kbd> button and give a name to the view
- When you want to use those settings again, go to `Custom View` and select the view from the list of all custom views you have defined.

These steps are laid out in detail [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-multiple-print-ranges-in-excel/).